# Find gradle path on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle

I have gradle installed on my Ubuntu 15.10 System.I want to find the location where it is.
I am following [this article](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html). Here it is given that sample program can be found at `samples/java/quickstart`.
I want to open this sample program and for this I want to find location of gradle on my system, which I have downloaded from the  official gradle site, and installed using ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's multiple ways to locate where `gradle` is actually installed on your computer :

- `locate` : will locate where the bin `gradle` is on your computer. Assuming, `gradle` is on your `PATH`. It will most likely locate gradle in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/share` directory. If it locates the symbolic link use either `ls -l` or `readlink` to see where the bin is actually located.
- `which` : similar as `locate`
- `find` : to use at end if neither `locate` neigher `which` worked. It's the "brutal" way. You can use `find / -name "gradle" 2> /dev/null` to find all occurence of gradle (exact match) on your computer.

Comment: I am so stupid, now it says: Task 'locate' not found in root project ''. How do I actually launch the command?

Comment: @Neon are you inside a terminal, typing `locate gradle`?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that `locate` is command for terminal.

Answer (score 5):

`/usr/lib/gradle/default` -> `/usr/lib/gradle/5.x.x`
the former is a link file targeted to actual directory which is the version you currently using.

apt install gradle in Ubuntu 18.10

---

`which` will locate to `/usr/bin/gradle` which is gradle start up script.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS in WSL2 in Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19043 N/A Build 19043):

```
$ sudo apt install gradle

$ which gradle
/usr/bin/gradle

$ readlink -f /usr/bin/gradle
/usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle

$ gradle --version
Gradle 4.4.1
Groovy:       2.4.17
```

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu 20+

```
 /home/[user]/.gradle
```

Comment: Is that really true? I thought, it contains only the wrapper?